# JOLT Transform from Prefix Soup to Nested

Tags: arrays, json, nested, apache-nifi, jolt

I´m receiving this JSON as part of a SQL Query and I want to create nested objects out of the composed properties. This can be done easily if it was 1 element, but the MYSQL query returns an array right at the root:

```json
[
  {
    "idlicense": 1,
    "StartDate": "2022-11-15 00:00:00.0",
    "EndDate": "2022-11-29 00:00:00.0",
    "MonthlySearchMax": 500,
    "Customer_CustomerId": 0,
    "Customer_Guid": "c24c1fa3-0388-4c08-b431-8d0f05fe263a",
    "Customer_Name": "User",
    "Customer_CustStartDate": "2022-11-15 00:00:00.0",
    "Connector_ConnectorId": 0,
    "Connector_Name": "connector0",
    "Connector_Version": "1.01"
  },
  {
    "idlicense": 2,
    "StartDate": "2022-11-15 00:00:00.0",
    "EndDate": "2022-11-29 00:00:00.0",
    "MonthlySearchMax": 500,
    "Customer_CustomerId": 0,
    "Customer_Guid": "c24c1fa3-0388-4c08-b431-8d0f05fe263a",
    "Customer_Name": "User",
    "Customer_CustStartDate": "2022-11-15 00:00:00.0",
    "Connector_ConnectorId": 1,
    "Connector_Name": "connector1",
    "Connector_Version": "1.01"
  }
]
```

I´m trying to create a nested JSON with JOLT on NIFI but can´t find the right format looking at the available examples and seems to be simple. I need my final JSON to look like this:

```
{
  "Licenses": [
    {
      "idLicense": "1",
      "Customer": {
        "CustomerId": "0",
        "Guid": "c24c1fa3-0388-4c08-b431-8d0f05fe263a",
        "Name": "User",
        "CustStartDate": "2022-11-15 00:00:00.0"
      },
      "Connector": {
        "ConnectorId": "0",
        "Name": "Connector0",
        "Version": "1.01"
      }
    },
    {
      "idLicense": "2",
      "Customers": {
        "CustomerId": "1",
        "Guid": "c24c1fa3-0388-4c08-b431-8d0f05fe263a",
        "Name": "User",
        "CustStartDate": "2022-11-15 00:00:00.0"
      },
      "Connector": {
        "ConnectorId": "1",
        "Name": "Connector1",
        "Version": "1.01"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

So far I´ve done this JOLT transform:

```
{
  "idlicense": [1,2],
  "Customer": {
    "CustomerId": [0,0],
    "Guid": ["c24c1fa3-0388-4c08-b431-8d0f05fe263a","c24c1fa3-0388-4c08-b431-8d0f05fe263a"],
    "Name": ["User","User"],
    "CustStartDate": ["2022-11-15 00:00:00.0","2022-11-15 00:00:00.0"]
  },
  "Connector": {
    "ConnectorId": [0,1],
    "Name": ["Conector0","Connector1"],
    "Version": ["1.01","1.01"]
  }
}
```

thank you for your support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this **shift** transformation spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "idlicense": "Licenses[&1].&",
        "*_*": "Licenses[&1].&(0,1).&(0,2)"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

where **&(0,1)** represents before, **&(0,2)** after underscore character

Comment: just as a challenge, sometimes the result has [ ] at the root, sometimes it doesnt, depending on existing 1 or more results. Is there something conditional we can do to address this? I´m trying to avoid any pre-processing code.

Comment: it depends on the cases @FilipeMiguelFerreira , it's important to count the deepness of the tree considering a Jolt problem. An extra `[]` might be added for cases in which there exists probability of returning only one oject/attribute.